# Elasticsearch _reindex API not copying documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to upgrade an old 1.5 elastic index to 6.0, according to docs (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/reindex-upgrade.html) 
I can create a new index in 6.0 and then use reindex from remote using reindex from remote (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/reindex-upgrade-remote.html)

**Both of these instances are running inside docker containers** I just wanted to test this in local before actually doing it in production

**I can see there are documents indexed in my old index.**

`curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/old_index/_search?pretty'`

```
{
  "took" : 8,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "old_index",
      "_type" : "item",
      "_id" : "92",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":{"user_id":3,"slug":"asdfaisjeilej","name":"lake.jpgasdad","item_type":"image","created_at":"2018-01-23T18:11:30Z","deleted_at":null,"content_length":1252171}
    }]}
}
```

After creating a new index (`new_index`) in my elasticsearch 6.0 instance, with a slightly diff mapping (change string types to text), I then proceed to reindex from remote using the following command. (note than my other instance is running in port 9400)

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9400/_reindex?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "source": {
    "remote": {
      "host": "http://localhost:9200"
    },
    "index": "old_index"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "new_index"
  }
}
```

I get the following response

```
{
  "took" : 136,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "total" : 0,
  "updated" : 0,
  "created" : 0,
  "deleted" : 0,
  "batches" : 0,
  "version_conflicts" : 0,
  "noops" : 0,
  "retries" : {
    "bulk" : 0,
    "search" : 0
  },
  "throttled_millis" : 0,
  "requests_per_second" : -1.0,
  "throttled_until_millis" : 0,
  "failures" : [ ]
}
```

So basically, documents from old_index are not being copied to new_index, and I have no idea why this is happening. Is there a step I'm missing, I'm following elasticsearch docs exactly as they read apparently.

Comment: Did you make sure to configure `reindex.remote.whitelist` in your new ES 6 cluster?

Comment: Yeah, that's all setup and pointing to `9200`

Comment: Also docker containers in local?

Comment: Yes, both containers in local. I noticed that if I try with a non existent destination index I keep getting a successful response instead of a `index_not_found` exception. So I wonder if it's a problem with elastic itself.

Comment: I am having the same issues. this needs an answer.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. It's worked for me when I tried to do this on staging environment but without Dockers.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned, I also had the same issue while migrating from Elasticsearch-2 to Elasticsearch-6 after I tested the remote-reindexing in staging environment without dockers.
My workaround was to create an instance of the old version (not on docker), load it from backup and reindex from it to elasticsearch 6 instance that not running on docker.

If you still want to run elasticsearch 6 on docker you can always mount the data to your container.

Hope you find it helpful.